# Facebook Custom Tab: i can't get FacebookSession under subpages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I wanted to integrate my website (not all just a specific section) under facebook tab and retrieve user info, i succeeded to get it done. but the problem is that i can't get user info when i navigate throw the site pages.

For example if i use:
 mysite.org/foo as primary page, here i can get required user info without any problem.
but when i navigate to mysite.org/foo/bar then session return null.

```
   \Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
    $helper = new \Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();

    try {
        $session = $helper->getSession();
    } catch (\Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e) {
        echo "Exception occured, code: ".$e->getCode();
        echo " with message: ".$e->getMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception occured, code: ".$e->getCode();
        echo " with message: ".$e->getMessage();
    }
```

I'm using javascript sdk for logging

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : APP_KEY,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          console.log('Logged in.');
        }
        else {
          console.log('Logging.');
          FB.login(function(response) {},{scope: 'email'});
        }
    });
  };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :)

I have to replace all links in the site with post request and send 'signed_request' within.

here is the solution that may need some improvements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('<form name="temp" method="POST"/>');
    $form.append('<input type="hidden" name="signed_request" value="<?=$_REQUEST['signed_request']; ?>" />');
    $form.appendTo($('body'));

    $('a').click(function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(!isExternal(href)){
            e.preventDefault();
            $form.attr('action',href);
            $form.submit();
        }
    });

    function isExternal(url) {
       var match = url.match(/^([^:\/?#]+:)?(?:\/\/([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]+)?(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?/);
       if (typeof match[1] === "string" && match[1].length > 0 && match[1].toLowerCase() !== location.protocol) return true;
       if (typeof match[2] === "string" && match[2].length > 0 && match[2].replace(new RegExp(":("+{"http:":80,"https:":443}[location.protocol]+")?$"), "") !== location.host) return true;
      return false;
    }
});</script>
```